# Creating a jquery dialog as an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dialog

In my current application I am using jquery UI dialog at many places , so I am planning to create a method like

```
 var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};

   MYAPP.overlay = (function(){
       $("#id").dialog();

   }());
```

This is my idea but now the problem is my overlay is used for different purpose like overlay form, video, confirmation message etc.  Is there a way I can have all the option inside my API . so I just have to call MYAPP.overlay("video",some other parameter) and it will create the overlay without have to repeat the code again and again....any idea or suggestion  will be appreciated..

Comment: Why not have a set id for the container as part of your API so that the API is agnostic to what it actually displays?  Just have it look for the id "myContainer" or something.

Comment: yeah thats a good idea ....this way i can have more control in my API..and i should have different id for different container like video, form etc...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the immediately executing anonymous function, but you can do something like this:

```
MYAPP.overlay = function MYAPP$overlay(id, paramsObj) {
    // do something based on element type, id, or params obj here.
    $(id).dialog();

    // possibly return something if needed.
};
```

Comment: ignore immediate executing anonymous function...its just a skeleton..yeah I am planning to do same thing but if i just want to call MYAPP.overlay("video", and other params); it will just create the overlay with the videos(as an object ) ... .

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use parameters. here is a very generic way of doing it:

```
MYAPP.overlay = (function(){
        // complex code ....

        return function(arg) {
          alert(arg);
        }
     })();

// example
MYAPP.overlay('hello');
```

will alert hello

Comment: You can certainly do it that way, I'm just not sure why the closure is needed (based on the question).

Comment: yeah thats the basic skeleton to achieve what I am planning but I just want to pass the feature as an string like MYAPP.overlay("video", obj); and it will create the overlay...

Comment: simply add a second argument to the function. `function(string,obj)` that write the code to create the overlay...